# Monteverdi input Aeronet data

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

How does one input NASA Aeronet data successfully into Monteverdi for atmospheric correction? I have downloaded a level 2 combined almucantar product but I get the error: `ERROR:  The file 130101_131231_GSFC.dubovik is not conform.`

I am uncertain what file format it is expecting. Does anyone have an example of the formatted input or data type from Aeronet?

Answer (score 1):

I think that level 2 is supported by OTB.

Can you try with Monteverdi2 and the OpticalCalibration application?

Here are examples of aeronet files use to test optical calibration in OTB:

http://hg.orfeo-toolbox.org/OTB-Data/file/tip/Input/AERONET